# Можно ли определить переменную не указывая её тип, даже auto?

Tags: c++

Можно ли в C++ определить переменную, не указывая явно её тип (даже `auto`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Такая возможность есть, по-крайней мере, в области захвата лямбда-функции (c++14). Отсутствие типа в данном контексте воспринимается так же как если бы переменная была объявлена с типом `auto` в локальном контексте. Пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    int x = 42;
    const std::string s = "now";

    auto f = [&r = x, c = "text", s = s]() mutable {
        r = 100500; 
        s[0] = 'w';
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    };

    std::cout << x << "\n";
    f();

    std::cout << x << "\n";
    std::cout << s << "\n"; 
}
```

Здесь `r` имеет тип `int&`, `c` - `const char*`, `s` (внутри тела лямбды) - `std::string`.

<kbd>[Вывод:](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/i4Nf0X5mJKOJIsvZ)</kbd>

> ```
> 42  
> wow
> 100500
> now
> ```

Comment: Этот ответ неверный, `r`, `c`, `s` (внутри) не являются переменными.

Comment: @user7860670, а чем они являются?

Comment: non-static data members объекта

Comment: @user7860670 see 6.1, 6.2 https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#6